# Laravel: В зависимости от роли поменять стартовую страницу

Tags: laravel

Доброе!
Собственно сабж. Добавил в проект роли. Теперь при входе пользователю с ролью "роль_1" нужно направить на страницу "страница роли 1" И соответственно с другой ролью. Меня больше не реализация, а подход интересует. Как это правильно делать?
Видится, например, такой подход: У всех пользователей при логине открывается одна и та же страница, но внутри страницы через @if в зависимости от роли идет перенаправление...
Или, создаем для логина один класс, а в классе через render() возвращаем return view(...) ту или иную страницу.
Как правильнее, как это делается?

Answer (score 0):

Если просто при входе и один раз (то есть потом пользователь может куда угодно переходить), то я бы просто сделал `protected $redirectTo = *Какой-нибудь адрес*;` в LoginController который кинет на контроллер который сделает редирект в зависимости от роли. Если же нельзя пересекаться ролям (админка например) то тут уже только middleware спасут. Делаешь то же самое, но для всех изолированных друг от друга маршрутов назначаешь миддлвары.

Comment: да, будет и админка, и другие странички куда всем нельзя лезть. Пример бы того как это реализовано...обучалка типа...